# Can we make dua to ask for the highest point in Jannah (heaven)?

Tags: dua, jannah

Can we make dua to ask for the highest point in Jannah (heaven)?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.**

---

Abu Horaira reported that the Prophet (peace be upon him) said:

> 'When you ask from Allah, ask Him for Al Firdaus, for it is the middle of Paradise and it is the highest place and from it the rivers of Paradise flow.' - In sahih Bukhary and Muslim

Comment: To add to your answer "**Whosoever desires (with his deeds) the reward of the Hereafter, We give him increase in his reward**, and whosoever desires the reward of this world (with his deeds), We give him thereof (what is written for him), and he has no portion in the Hereafter. (Qur'an 42:20)"

Comment: And what is the best Supplication that guarantee the highest level in Heaven?

Answer (score 2):

This question could be surveyed from two different aspects:

1. As the initial aspect it would be said that solely praying (dua) for the highest point in Jannah won’t be sufficient. Since you should have good deed to be hopeful that Allah takes you to the highest points… otherwise as a rational rule, Allah won’t give us high point without having good deeds (just to say it by our tongues...)
2. On the other aspect, we should be hopeful regarding the promotion of
   our high-point, since Allah has declared in the Holy Qur'an that “Call
   upon Me; I will respond to you”, consequently it indicates that pray
   (dua) would be effective in granting the desires and needs that Allah
   himself mentioned it. Anyhow we should be hopeful about anything
   along with having good deeds.

---

Look at the following verse of the Holy Quran which could be related to your inquiry.

> وَقَالَ رَبُّكُمُ ادْعُونِي أَسْتَجِبْ لَكُمْ ۚ إِنَّ الَّذِينَ
>   يَسْتَكْبِرُونَ عَنْ عِبَادَتِي سَيَدْخُلُونَ جَهَنَّمَ دَاخِرِينَ
>   ﴿٦٠
>
> And your Lord says, "Call upon Me; I will respond to you." Indeed,
>   those who disdain My worship will enter Hell [rendered] contemptible.
>   (60)

---

**Reference(s):**

- [www.tebyan.net](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=934&articleID=424792)
- [http://tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/40:60)

Comment: In the meanwhile, reading the following site would be beneficial for you as a related site. (in u r familiar with Farsi(persian)) : http://www.aviny.com/hadis-mozooee/ebadi/doa.aspx

Answer (score 0):

yes but if you are looking for higher places you should doing some "niko"("اعمال صالح")(god things )there was group in imam ali age and they just pray an stick into mountains and..(they called soofi) and one day imam ali told that way is not true.
Islam needs doing good things like charity and some times defending against enemys and..